# C# MongoDb Driver Filter using nested property from collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following class structures :

```
public class QuoteRequestInfo
{
      . . . 
    public LocationInfo LocationInfo {get;set;}
     . . .
}
```

`LocationInfo` has a stop collection which will always contain 2 stops :

```
public class LocationInfo
{
    . . . 
    public IEnumerable<Stop> Stops{get;set};
     . . .
}
```

`Stop` has the following property :

```
public class Stop
{
    . . . 
    public string StateName {get;set};
     . . .
}
```

I am trying to search `QuoteRquestInfos` collection by filtering on multiple state names like so :

```
var states = new List<string> {"VA"}
var filter =  Builders<QuoteRequestInfo>.Filter.In(r => r.LocationInfo.Stops.First().StateCode, states)
var quotes = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

This is returning an empty filter and not matching anything? how should I be passing in the expression to the In Filter ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways, for example:

```
        var states = new List<string> { "VA" };
        var quotes = coll.AsQueryable()
            .Select(c =>
                new {
                    Previous = new QuoteRequestInfo { LocationInfo = c.LocationInfo }, // this partocular line saves the previous document
                    StoredFirst = c.LocationInfo.Stops.First().StateName }) // save a flag about first stop since call it in the same construction with `Where` is not supported via typed way
            .Where(f => states.Contains(f.StoredFirst))
            .Select(c => c.Previous)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Thic could work but I was specifically trying to find a solution with out converting the Collection to Queryable .

Comment: it doesn't matter. `AsQueryable` just calls `Aggregate` behind the scene. So you can replace the above `Select` on `Aggregate.Project` and `Where` on `Aggregate.Match`. As I can see, you can't use Find only because it doesn't support using Projection before filtering

Comment: If you need Find, you can simply provide a filter in raw MQL form like: `var quotes = await collection.Find("{ whatever : 1 }").ToListAsync();`